# Using NUnit+Reflection, can't find any events on my ActiveX control

Tags: c#, event-handling, activex, system.reflection

I'm unit-testing an old-school COM/ActiveX control using NUnit and C#.
I'm doing everything dynamically, no References or compile-time type information, because the control I'm testing is used primarily from javascript - which, of course, does everything dynamically. I want to hook up some event handlers and make sure events are being fired appropriately, but I can't *find* the events!  I dynamically construct an instance of the control using System.Activator.CreateInstance, like this (some details omitted ;-):

```
Type T = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid);
eztwain = System.Activator.CreateInstance(T);
EZTwainX = eztwain.GetType();
```

Tests of properties and methods work fine, like so:

```
EZTwainX.InvokeMember("Clear", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, eztwain, null);
Assert.AreEqual(0, (int)EZTwainX.InvokeMember("ImageCount", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, eztwain, null), "ImageCount");
```

The following all fail, returning null or an empty array or throwing a 'name not found' exception as appropriate:

```
EZTwainX.GetEvent("AcquireDone");           // returns null
EZTwainX.GetEvents();                       // returns empty array
EZTwainX.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Public |    // returns empty array
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = EZTwainX.GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);      // returns null
MemberInfo[] mimfo = EZTwainX.GetMember("AcquireDone", MemberTypes.Event, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);      // returns empty array
```

I just assumed (ahem) that I could do something using the Reflection API, equivalent to:

```
eztwain.AcquireDone += <event handler>;
```

but I can't figure out what that equivalent thing is.
EDIT: I believe in that event on that control because in Javascript this works (and catches events):

```
eztwain.attachEvent("AcquireDone", function() { me.onAcquireDone(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to: Handle Events Raised by a COM Source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gUyRBjzUrFoJ:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66ahbe6y(v%3Dvs.110).aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Also, Notice the utility you can use ([Ildasm.exe (IL Disassembler)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx)) to get event signatures.